# Using require within an NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm

I've written a custom NPM package that will spin up a mocked Apollo GraphQL server for me with some custom settings.

In my `/bin` folder I have a file, `server.js` which is responsible for spinning up the server.

In `package.json` I've set up my command like this:

```
...
"bin": {
  "mock-server": "./src/server.js"
},
...
```

So when I run the command `mock-server` from the parent project it will execute the `server.js` file.

All good so far, but the problem is that once I start trying to require dependencies I run into this error:

```
$ use-env mock-server
/Users/dev/projects/share-vde-frontend/node_modules/.bin/mock-server: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/dev/projects/share-vde-frontend/node_modules/.bin/mock-server: line 1: `const { ApolloServer  } = require("apollo-server");'
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

My knowledge of writing npm modules is just based on what I've seen in packages I've been using in the past, so maybe I'm missing something key. Do I need some special measures when requiring imports? Or do I need to build and transpile the code? I'm using ES6 syntax, but I feel confident that anyone using this package will be on modern Node.js versions (the package is private and only to be used within our organisation).

Comment: I don't think that's an error from JavaScript, but from your *shell*; does `server.js` have a `#!` line defining the executable to use?

Comment: No it does not. I thought that was only for bash scripts. How am I supposed to set it up?

Comment: That *is* now a shell script, that's what making it a `bin` executable means. Read https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin.

Comment: Oh! That was the missing link. Works now after adding shabang.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @jonrsharpe above, I solved it by added shabang to the start of the `server.js` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");
...
```

Comment: Note that doesn't make it a binary executable (and you also need to make the file executable with e.g. `chmod u+x <file>`), it just tells your shell what executable to *use* to run it.